# Gulp: how to use CDN for js lib?

Tags: javascript, angular, gulp

I'm new in AngularJS and Gulp.

In one example, some libs are copied by Gulp from the `node_modules` folder in a `js/lib/angular2` folder:

```
gulp.task('libs', function() {
 return gulp.src([
  'node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js'
    ... // other libs
 ]).pipe(gulp.dest(src + 'js/lib/angular2'));
});
```

then added in `index.html` via script tag

```
<script src="js/lib/angular2/angular2.dev.js"></script>
```

What if I would load them via CDN?

During development I can use local js files, copied by Gulp, but in production have I substitute them "by hand" with their corresponding CDN file (if any)? or there is a way to do it directly with Gulp?

**EDIT**

I found the plugin [gulp-cdnizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cdnizer)

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin for gulp, gulp-processhtml, that can do this. It uses conditional comments that will remove/replace/add to your HTML files based on the gulp task.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-processhtml

Comment: I found another plugin [gulp-cdnizer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-cdnizer)